# Get count of all rows for Druid Native GroupBy Query

Tags: group-by, druid

I need to get a count of all rows for group-by query with all the dimensions applied

```
    {
        "queryType": "groupBy",
        "dataSource": {
            "type": "table",
            "name": "employee"
        },
        "intervals": {
            "type": "intervals",
            "intervals": [
                "-146136543-09-08T08:23:32.096Z/146140482-04-24T15:36:27.903Z"
            ]
        },
        "virtualColumns": [],
        "granularity": {
            "type": "all"
        },
        "dimensions": [
            {
                "type": "default",
                "dimension": "department",
                "outputName": "department",
                "outputType": "STRING"
            },
            {
                "type": "default",
                "dimension": "standard",
                "outputName": "standard",
                "outputType": "STRING"
            },
            {
                "type": "default",
                "dimension": "vocational",
                "outputName": "vocational",
                "outputType": "STRING"
            },
            {
                "type": "default",
                "dimension": "lab",
                "outputName": "lab",
                "outputType": "STRING"
            }
        ],
        "having": null,
        "descending": false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add an aggregation as well:

```
"aggregations": [{"type":"count", "name":"row_count"}]
```

Comment: Aggregation like the above will give a count at each bucket(of dimensions) level. But it won't provide the total result count, I can use limitSpec and can understand what is the max by playing around with different offsets and limits. But not the straightforward way to get the count